# How can I rip a copyprotected audio cd

Tags: cd-ripping

Banshee hangs when I try to load an audio cd with "bmg-copycontrol". The same with sound juicer. How can I extract it?

According to wikipedia this copy control was used during 2001-2006. The web page, which is near the copy-control logo is not accessible any more.

Comment: To whoever is voting to close this, if you still think this should be closed, please comment (or post on meta) explaining why. If this is a bug, that would justify closing it, but I don't think it's a bug. If you think this should be closed because you're against helping people circumvent copying and use restrictions on their own media, please realize that [the overall network policy on this is that such content is allowed](http://meta.superuser.com/a/2215/105707). If you think Ask Ubuntu should suppress such content, **please post on meta to discuss it and get community consensus first**.

Comment: @EliahKagan Well put and thanks for that link. To anyone anonymously down-voting or close-voting you really should read Jeff's linked post before deciding what to do. This is on-topic and applicable to a wide audience.

Comment: I would add to @EliahKagan 's statement that it has been discussed before and that this one in particular, I feel, falls under the allowed guidance portion: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2971/copyright-and-morality-in-questions

Comment: Did you try Handbrake,

Answer (score 8):

In my case it worked with the command line tool "abcde".

If your system starts an application (banshee) automatically if an audio cd is inserted, then you need to wait until this application opens. In my case this needs some minutes. Then close the application, this will release the dbus lock on the device. After that "abcde" can read the CD.

Metadata (singer, title, ...) are added by the tool. Works nice, I am happy.

Comment: Can you please add some more detail to your answer? If you detail the steps it's a huge help to those reading your answer later.

Answer (score 4):

This will not really help you by what you are doing but it still might help you in creating a copy of a copy protected music CD.

[And just for the protocol: Everybody should have the right to create a backup copy of any CD bought. I myself do have a car CD player that "eaty" my CDs after a while. So if I do not have a copy - shall I always buy a new one???]

My solution:
I just take the output of a sound CD and record it with audacity. Then you have a copy of the CD and it should only have really almost unhearable copy loss. These files you can burn again to an audio CD without copy protection.

I know it is not really the fastest way but it works at last. :)

I am not sure if the following will help you but I once had luck as well with an older Linux System and an older CD-Rom drive that just did not care about copy protection. But since I do not have this PC anymore I just record them in audacity ...

Good luck!

[It once worked in XP?](http://forum.dbpoweramp.com/archive/index.php?t-1643.html)

Comment: My 20 years old audio-cd player can play the CD. But several DVD drives don't. In Germany you are allowed to make backups for yourself. If I just record the CD, I don't have the convenience that the audio files are automatically tagged with CDDB.

Answer (score 3):

As someone who just received a CD with a book but no longer owns a CD player independent of my PC (Gnome Ubuntu 14.04/Gnome 3.12) I have to say that in this situation the copyright issues don't seem to apply or if they do they are unfair.  I simply want access to "my" CD.

In response to the request for information on how to do this, first install abcde:

```
sudo apt-get install abcde
```

Then run abcde in terminal

```
abcde
```

It reads the CD, asks you a couple of questions copies the tracks to your computer.  For more information see this helpful [HowTo](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=109429).

Apparently a program named cdparanoia will also address the issue of accessing product that you have paid for already.